I am receiving a response url not found on server when I try to delete file in Google Drive using a Linux bash script and curl
I am trying to delete a file using a bash shell script that I uploaded to a shared google drive using a different shell script. I am able to list the contents of the folder that the file is in and return the filenames and fileids. however when I try and delete the file the response says that the requested url was not found on the server.
The functions I call from within the shell script are below. The file id must be valid as it is correctly echoed and matches a link to the file obtained through Google Drive itself. I am correctly setting Access token.
I have tried various approaches to specify the file should be trashed/deleted such as using DELETE instead of POST and played around with file id by adding the full link from Google Drive and other connotations, without success. I had expected the response to be successful!
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Function to get a new access token using the refresh token

get_access_token() {
    RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token \
        -d client_id=${CLIENT_ID} \
        -d client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET} \
        -d refresh_token=${REFRESH_TOKEN} \
        -d grant_type=refresh_token)

    ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo ${RESPONSE} | jq -r '.access_token')
    echo -e "Access token acquired '${ACCESS_TOKEN}'"
}

get_drive_contents () {

    DRIVE_CONTENTS=$(curl -s GET \
        "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='${DRIVE_ID}'+in+parents+and+trashed=false&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&fields=files(id,name,mimeType)" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        -H "Accept: application/json")

    echo -e ${DRIVE_CONTENTS}   
}

delete_files () {
    echo $DRIVE_CONTENTS | jq -c -r '.files[]' | while read item; do
        FILE_ID=$(echo ${item} | jq -r '.id')
        FILENAME=$(echo ${item} | jq -r '.name')
        echo "fileid=$FILE_ID filename=$FILENAME"

    echo -e "Delete file request"
    DELETE_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'${FILE_ID}'?supportsAllDrives=true" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{"trashed": true}')

    echo -e "DELETE url response: $DELETE_RESPONSE"

    exit
done

}   

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Error: list_gdrive.sh requires 1 parameter"
    echo -e "Usage: $0 gdrive_full_path"
    echo -e "Example gdrive full path :https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Jm4UDqJDDo4-frwjoHsK_qqcDHRZjDkD"
    exit 1
fi

DRIVE_URL=$1

echo -e "Gdrive: $DRIVE_URL"

CLIENT_ID="xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxx"
REFRESH_TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxx}

get_access_token

ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.access_token')

echo -e "Access Token initialized"

get_drive_contents

delete_files

echo -e "All processing complete"

exit 0


An interesting bunch of code, but seems to be way too much for identifying the problem. Please read  the section How to turn a bad script into a good question (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash). Good luck

Modification points:

If you want to use "Method: files.update" of Drive API v3, please use the PATCH method instead of the POST method. Ref
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'${FILE_ID}'?supportsAllDrives=true should be https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${FILE_ID}?supportsAllDrives=true

When these points are reflected in your script, please modify your script as follows and test it again.
From:
DELETE_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'${FILE_ID}'?supportsAllDrives=true" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"trashed": true}')

To:
DELETE_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X PATCH "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${FILE_ID}?supportsAllDrives=true" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"trashed": true}')


By this modification, the file ${FILE_ID} is moved to the trash box.
When I tested this modified script, I confirmed that the file was moved to the trash box.

Note:

This modification supposes that the values ${FILE_ID} and $ACCESS_TOKEN are valud values. Please be careful about this.

Reference:

Method: files.update of Drive API v3


This worked but now I am getting the message "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."

@Peter Libman Thank you for replying. About This worked, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About but now I am getting the message "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.", the reason for your current issue is due to The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.. So, please confirm it again. When I tested my proposed modification to valid file, I can confirm that no error occurs. I apologize for this situation.
